# Reviewer rejects edit and then makes the same edit

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I made an edit suggestion but it was rejected and then one of the users who rejected the edit made the same edit. How to handle this situation?

Comment: Shrug it off and move on?

Comment: Stop edit-farming?

Comment: Probably a 'collision' of edit suggestions, as @JonW said shrug it off and move on

Comment: While it sounds "malicious", it could have been that the user who rejected it later realised it was a good edit. But anyway, it's +2 reputation. Unless a pattern emerges, don't give it too much importance.

Comment: You can conclude a lot of things from the reviewer's character :D